# Ad-hoc style distribution for an iPad app?

Tags: iphone, adhoc

I'm talking with a client who is abroad and I'm wondering whether I will be able to send him versions of the iPad app for testing before it's on iTunes.

Is there a solution (e.g. Ad-Hoc?) I could rely that doesn't require jailbreak or anything?

If so, could you please provide me with a link to a guide?

Thank you !

Comment: On top of the other posts, I recommend [TestFlight](http://testflightapp.com).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes Ad-hoc is what you need, basically you will need to associate your client device identifier (UDID) to a certificate that you will use to sign application.

This is a standard procedure (no jailbreak required) that is fully documented on [Apple provisioning portal](http://developer.apple.com/ios/manage/overview/index.action) in [User Program Guide](http://developer.apple.com/ios/download.action?path=/ios/ios_developer_program_user_guide/ios_developer_program_user_guide__standard_program_v2.7__final_9110.pdf) *(you have to apply ($99) for the developer program and be logged to access this... and it is limited to 100 devices)*

Another good thing is to use an "Ad-Hoc" updater such as [HockeyKit](https://github.com/TheRealKerni/HockeyKit) to ease your client updates and installation procedure...

Answer (score 1):

Yes, indeed, there is an ad-hoc distribution method:
[here is its mention](http://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/distribute.html) on the Apple Developer website. As far as details, I think you have to be in the developer program in order to get direct documentation for that, and sadly I allowed my developer account to lapse. A few key points can be found [here](http://spin.atomicobject.com/2010/12/29/ios-distribution-methods/)

Essentially, you can distribute to up to 100 other iOS users who have your group's apple developer credentials installed on their phone, and the app will remain live for 90 days

Essentially, it's the same headache on the remote side with certs, keys, etc... that you have to do with XCode when developing on the device, but you can put the app on a website somewhere where the remote party can install it on their phone.

EDIT: I found [this guide](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/35818-unofficial-ad-hoc-distribution-guide.html) that is presented on a forum if you want to look through the steps.